# How to merge multiple JSON objects into a Python DataFrame based on timestamp?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a graphql query that returns a string of JSON-formatted data, with 3 separate JSON objects inside. It looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "readingsList": [
      {
        "value": 137,
        "millis": 1651449224000
      },
      {
        "value": 141,
        "millis": 1651448924000
      }
    ],
    "messagesList": [
      {
        "value": 138,
        "dateMillis": 1651445346000,
        "text": "foo",
        "type": "bar",
        "field1": False
      }
    ]
    "userList": [
      {
        "userTimezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is

1. **Merge the first two objects (`readingsList` and `messagesList`) based on the time (`millis` and `dateMillis`) into a dataframe**
2. Convert that time into a UTC datetime value (e.g. 1651449224000 becomes 2022-05-01 18:53:44)
3. Convert the UTC datetime value into local time for the user based on the users Timezone from `userList`

Desired output:

```
df.head(3)

    datetime             value   text   type   field1   ...
    2022-05-01 18:53:44  137     NA     NA     NA
    2022-05-01 18:48:44  141     NA     NA     NA
    2022-05-01 17:49:06  138     foo    bar    False
```

I can do steps 2 and 3 but I don't know how to do step 1.

If I convert the string using `json.loads()` and `pd.read_json()` I get the following output:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

json_str = load_data_gql(...)
j = json.loads(json_str)
df = pd.read_json(j)

df.head()

                  data
    groupsList    [{'userTimezone': 'America/Los_Angeles'}]
    messagesList  [{'value': 138, 'dateMillis': 1651445346000, ...
    readingsList  [{'value': 137, 'millis': 1651449224000}, {'value'...
```

I now suspect that the answer has to somehow do with [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) but I'm having difficulty applying what I read in that documentation to navigate my JSON objects properly.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Proposed Solution:

Merging the dataframes in this case can be done with `pandas.concat([df_1,df_2])`

Here's the code I used:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

json_obj = json.load(open('json_str_file.json', 'r')) # if reading from file
# json_obj = json.loads(json_str) # if reading from a string

# create two separate frames from each nested dictionary object
df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_obj['data']['messagesList'])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_obj['data']['readingsList'])

# set the index to the column you want to merge them on
df_1.set_index('dateMillis', inplace=True)
df_2.set_index('millis', inplace=True)

# use pd.concat to stack the dataframes together
df_merged = pd.concat([df_1,df_2])

# fix field1 to be a boolean field
df_merged['field1'] = df_merged['field1'].astype(bool)

# confirm the result matches the target
print(df_merged)
```

#### Output

```
               value text type  field1
1651445346000    138  foo  bar   False
1651449224000    137  NaN  NaN    True
1651448924000    141  NaN  NaN    True
```

From here you should be able to do steps 2 and 3 from your post.

### Issues with the JSON

The example you gave had some formatting issues that might cause some confusion.  `messagesList` and `readingsList` needed to be separated by a ',' for me.  Also `json.load()` didn't like the value of `False` in my example.

Here is the reformatted JSON

```json
{
  "data": {
    "readingsList": [
      {
        "value": 137,
        "millis": 1651449224000
      },
      {
        "value": 141,
        "millis": 1651448924000
      }
    ],
    "messagesList": [
      {
        "value": 138,
        "dateMillis": 1651445346000,
        "text": "foo",
        "type": "bar",
        "field1": 0
      }
    ],
    "userList": [
      {
        "userTimezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Potential Confusion:

- JSON string could be formatted poorly
- `json.loads()` returns an object of type `dict` with nested elements.
- `pd.read_json()` expects a object of type `str`
- using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` works with `dict` objects and allows you to address the nested components like this: `j['data']['messagesList']`

Comment: clear, concise, perfect. Thank you so much. I was clearly thinking about this in the wrong way. Thank you for outlining the confusing portions as well - I will update my example to fix the JSON string. The only thing missing (which I never explicitly asked for so no fault of yours) was that I had to also sort the index `df_merged.sort_index(inplace=True)`. Thank you again for your help!!